# Insert unique values into PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

```
 $dom = $html->find('.someClass',0)->find('.studentID');

$arr = array();

foreach ($dom as $data) {
    if(isset($data->find('.studentID',0)->plaintext)){

        $studentID = $data->find('.studentID',0)->plaintext;

            $arr[] = array(
                'studentID'=>$studentID
            );

    }

}
```

If I echo `$studentID` for example the result would be `123,345,345,567,123,567`  which my data contains redundant values.

What I want is only 123,345, and 567.

What should I do before assign $studentID into the $arr? I can't use in_array() because I loop through bunch of string, not an array in this case.

Comment: Have you seen `array_unique`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: @dan08 where should I put it? I put it outside of my loop, it has error of : Array to string conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible for you (there isn't enough code to be sure) to use the student id as a key in the $arr array. When you assign the data simply do this:

```
        $arr[$studentID] = array(
            'studentID'=>$studentID
        );
```

That way you know the student id will only appear once in the list. Just make sure you check the data structure carefully to make sure this is valid for your use case.

Comment: so this will avoid redundancy? because key cannot be redundant?

Comment: As long as you're only avoiding redundancy on the student id it should do that.

Comment: I tried and your solution worked! this is the most simple way to do it, why people are suggesting array_unique? is that work in my case? what do u think?

Comment: array_unique as azngunit81 suggests may work in your case but only if all data in the subarrays is always the same for each student id.
If you had a simple array of student ids then array_unique could be a good solution.

Comment: all data in subarrays? I don't get it.

Comment: You are creating a two-dimensional array, each instance in $arr contains an array, a subarray as I wrote there, subarray is probably the wrong term for it. But in order for array_unique to work on $arr all arrays containing a student id will have to contain the exact same extra data, say the student name for example.

Comment: u mean this? $array = array() ?I thought we must initialize before using an array?

Comment: no, when you do the $arr[] = array('studentId' => $studentID) you're creating a new array inside $arr

Comment: oh ya I see, didn't notice that! so I should just do like $arr[] = 'studentID' => $studentID right?

Comment: That will throw an error, if you only want to store the $studentID in the array you could do $arr[] = $studentID and then array_unique would become useful in your case. You could still use $arr[$studentID] = $studentID; and avoid using array_unique

Comment: we don't use array_unique because there's no need for it in this case, right?

Comment: You don't need it if you use this: $arr[$studentID] = $studentID;

Answer (score 0):

Take that information and put it into an array then do your in_array of any other type of comparisons. Like array_unique.

```
$studentIdArr = explode(", ", $studentId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking @dan08 answer

```
<?php
$result = array_unique($arr);
print_r($result);
?>
```

will return you a unique array of non-redundant values and type